# Alsamixer won't work with bluetooth device

Tags: linux, bluetooth, alsa

I'm running Debian unstable.  My `.asoundrc` looks like this:

```
pcm.btheadset
{
   type plug
   slave
   {
      pcm
      {
         type bluetooth
         device 5A:5A:5A:A6:08:09
         profile "auto"
      }
   }
}

ctl.btheadset
{
   type bluetooth
}
```

I can play music through the headset, however I cannot control the volume.

```
$ alsamixer -D btheadset
ALSA lib audio/ctl_bluetooth.c:167:(bluetooth_send_ctl) Unable to receive new volume value from server
ALSA lib audio/ctl_bluetooth.c:161:(bluetooth_send_ctl) Unable to request new volume value to server: Broken pipe
cannot load mixer controls: Broken pipe
```

`daemon.log` has this:

```
bluetoothd[15628]: Invalid message: length mismatch
```

Any ideas?  I suspected this may be some mismatch of binaries, so I tried downgrading `bluez` to Debian stable.  No luck.  Maybe I should try the same with alsa libs...

A lot of FAQs and tutorials suggest that PulseAudio should automatically solve this, however I installed it, it pulled down dozens of dependencies I have no interest in, and turned out to be a very user-hostile daemon that refused to play any sound at all.  So I am not interested in that as a solution.

Comment: You are invoking alsamixer correctly. Does your headset actually have mixer controls? This might be a bug in the bluetooth plugin.

Comment: @CL. - Not sure if the hardware supports it or not, or if it's a bug, but I've just discovered the "`softvol`" pcm type so now I'm happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a workaround.  Using alsa's `softvol` plugin to do volume control in software.

Added this to `.asoundrc`:

```
pcm.btheadset_softvol
{
   type softvol
   slave.pcm "btheadset"
   control.name "Bluetooth"
   control.card 0
}
```

Now I tell software to play to the device `btheadset_softvol` and my main sound card's mixer has a "Bluetooth" option.